# How to make a Flash IP to IP application, for sending a media?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, voip, red5

Without using Flash Media server or other media server for flash. How is it possible to send peer-to-peer packets straight? Can we send direct packets from one point to another?

I have tried with Red5 and realized it is horrible to do quality of packets switching by involving media server in the middle.

**Follow up:** P2PChatLocal.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="connect()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[           
            private var nc:NetConnection;
            private var group:NetGroup;

            [Bindable]
            private var userName:String;

            [Bindable]
            private var connected:Boolean = false;

            private function connect():void{
                nc = new NetConnection();
                nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatus);
                nc.connect("rtmfp:");

                userName = "user"+Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
            }

            private function netStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
                writeText(event.info.code);

                switch(event.info.code){
                    case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                        setupGroup();
                        break;

                    case "NetGroup.Connect.Success":
                        connected = true;
                        break;

                    case "NetGroup.Posting.Notify":
                        receiveMessage(event.info.message)
                        break;
                }
            }

            private function setupGroup():void{
                var groupspec:GroupSpecifier = new GroupSpecifier("myGroup/groupOne");
                groupspec.postingEnabled = true;
                groupspec.ipMulticastMemberUpdatesEnabled = true;
                groupspec.addIPMulticastAddress("225.225.0.1:30303");

                group = new NetGroup(nc,groupspec.groupspecWithAuthorizations());
                group.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatus);
            }

            private function sendMessage(txt:String):void{
                var message:Object = new Object();
                message.text = txt;
                message.sender = group.convertPeerIDToGroupAddress(nc.nearID);
                message.userName = txtUser.text;

                group.post(message);

                receiveMessage(message);
            }

            public function receiveMessage(message:Object):void{
                writeText(message.userName+": "+message.text);
            }

            private function writeText(txt:String):void{
                txtHistory.text += txt+"\n";
            }

            protected function btnSend_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                sendMessage( txtMessage.text );
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:TextInput text="{userName}" x="10" bottom="10" id="txtUser"/>
    <s:TextInput left="146" right="88" bottom="10" id="txtMessage" enter="btnSend_clickHandler(null)"/>
    <s:TextArea left="10" right="10" top="75" bottom="40" id="txtHistory"/>
    <s:Button enabled="{connected}" label="Send" bottom="10" right="10" click="btnSend_clickHandler(event)" id="btnSend"/>


</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible

First take a look at [Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/); which is Adobe's Solution.  It uses Real Time Media Flow Protocol (RTMFP); which I believe was introduced in Flash Player 10/AIR 2.

If you google a few other options come up.  Here is [one tutorial](http://www.flashrealtime.com/local-flash-peer-to-peer-communication-over-lan-without-cirrus/).

Comment: thank you. So i updated my above post. Thats the code to do Peer-to-peer? (yes its a sample, but this way you guys doing the media exchange, sounds cool).

Comment: Can you do the Full Duplex with this above code reference too?

Comment: @IamSon0fRaja Since you say "you Guys" I want to specify I, personally, have not done anything w/ Flashes P2P functionality.  I can't take any credit for the posts / resources out there.  It is interesting stuff;but not relevant to my current projects.